# Customized WindRose

Tags: r, openair

I am new in Rstudio. I am using library(openair) to plot a seasonal WindRose. I would like to know how I can change from English to spanish when I plot it and also how to set the season.

I mean, summer should be DJF and in the image it is JJA. Somebody could teach me how to change it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to change the labels to another language directly in an openair function. But you can do the following:

Classify the data according to the season of the southern hemisphere:

```r
library(openair)
newdata <- cutData(mydata, type = "season", hemisphere = "southern")
```

Change labels manually:

```r
levels(newdata$season) <- c("primavera (SON)", "verano (DEF)", "otoño (MAM)", "invierno (JJA)")
```

And, to graph.

```r
windRose(newdata, type = "season", paddle = F, key.position = "right")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Novvier, thank you. I already found out how it was. However I have one more question, My data is from 01-01-2019 to 29-02-2020. Is it possible to plot windRose only for 14 months, I have been trying and it plot all month, from january to dezember.

Comment: You can use the function selectByDate